# How to use Index in $lookup fields?

Tags: mongodb

My code is:

```
await createIndex("cases", { "info.relatedEntities.role": 1 } ),
await createIndex("entities", { "info.name": 1 } ),
const caseCollection = await getCaseCollection();
const cases = caseCollection.aggregate([
    { $match: { "info.relatedEntities.role": role} },
    { $lookup: {
            from: "entities",
            localField: "info.relatedEntities.entity",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "relatedEntities"
        }},
    { $match: { "relatedEntities.info.name": { $regex: name}}},
    { $limit: limit }
]);
```

But I see, that Index for entities is not being used, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Query explain does not show the index usage for the `from` expression in `$lookup` aggregation. Here is the [**jira**](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22622)

Comment: @Fanpark, even If i don't use explain, in NoSQLBooster I can check usage of index and I see that Index were not used.